# Three students are selected from a group of 10. What is the probability that George is selected if John is always one of the selected student.

Tags: probability

Since John is always selected, that leaves picking 2 students out of 9. So

$$P(G) =\frac{\binom 91}{\binom 92} =\frac 14$$

But this is wrong. What’s the problem here?

Comment: Since $2$ out of $9$ are being chosen, the answer is clearly $\frac 29$.  Phrased (slightly) differently) there are $8$ pairs containing $G$ and $\binom 92=36$ pairs in total so the answer is $\frac 8{36}=\frac 29$.

Comment: @lulu could you elaborate? We don’t have 2 George. Do you mean $\frac 19 +\frac 19$?

Comment: As for your attempt, you used a $9$ in the combination on the numerator when you shouldn't have.  Here, we have picked john, we are going to pick george... that leaves just one more person to pick *out of the remaining eight*, not nine.  $\dfrac{\binom{8}{1}}{\binom{9}{2}}=\dfrac{2}{9}$

Comment: @Aditya  I don't understand.  $\frac 19+\frac 19=\frac 29$ so what is your point?

Comment: As for the calculation of $\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{9}$, that is also a correct calculation and way to think of arriving at the answer here.  We assume *without loss of generality* that John is picked first.  Then George can be the second person picked with probability $\frac{1}{9}$ and the third person with probability $\frac{1}{9}$.  Noting that George cannot be the second and third person simultaneously, we can simply add these together for our answer.

Comment: The end result is that there are *many* ways of thinking of and approaching this problem, each of which if done correctly will yield the same answer, whether as $\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{9},\frac{\binom{8}{1}}{\binom{9}{2}},\frac{8}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9},\frac{2}{9}\times\frac{1}{3}\times 3,$ or however else you decide to organize your thoughts.  The important things to note are correctly keeping track of how many people there are at each point in time during your approach given what you are conditioning on and being consistent in your approach as to whether order does or doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

Let G be event that George is selected  and J be when John is selected .$$P(G|J)=\frac{n(G\cap J)}{n(J)}=\frac{\binom{8}{1}}{\binom{9}{2}}=2/9$$

**Explanation**: $n(J\cap G)=\binom{8}{1}$ as we are already having to select george and John and we are left to select one person from the rest $ 8$.

Comment: Probabilities cannot equal $8$.  What you have labeled as probabilities are not.

Comment: @JMoravitz sorry i meant n() i have fixed it

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about what went wrong with your approach:

I think your solution has a numerator of picking one student from $9$, but it should be $1$ student from $8$ since George and John will have been already selected in this scenario.

Then you get $\frac{8\choose1}{9\choose2}$ giving the correct answer of $\frac{8}{36}=\frac29$

Comment: But we need the probability of selecting George, so shouldn’t that factor into the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is simply $\frac{2}{9}$ as there are two spots leaving John. So for George to be selected, he has to be one of the two getting selected. Here is another way to look at it -

$P = \frac{8}{9} \times \frac{1}{8} +  \frac{1}{9} \times \frac{8}{8} = \frac{2}{9}$